# Mock Test Cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, caffeine-cache

I'm trying to test my cache layer with mockito.

I'm using Caffeine as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-caching-provider-caffeine)

Basically, I have this...

```
@Service
class Catalog {

  @Autowired
  Db db;

  @Cachable
  public List<Item> getItems() {
    // fetch from db
    db.someDbMethod();
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
class CatalogConfig {
  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new CaffeineCacheManager();
  }
  @Bean
  public Db db() {
     return new Db();
  }
}
// properties as in documentation etc
```

That works perfectly, the method is cached and works fine.

I want to add a test to verify the DB call is invoked only once, I have something like this but it's not working:

```
public class CatalogTest {

     @Mock
     Db db;

     @InjectMocks
     Catalog catalog;

     // init etc

     @Test
     void cache() {
       catalog.getItems();
       catalog.getItems();
       verify(db, times(1)).someDbMethod(); // fails... expected 1 got 2
     }
     // Some other passing tests below
     @Test
     void getItems() {
       assertNotNull(catalog.getItems()); // passes
     }
}
```

I've tried several combinations of `@Profile/@ActiveProfile`, `Config/ContextConfiguration` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had this case. I resolve it by partial bean's import and `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`:
I'll try to write the main idea:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Import({CaffeineCacheManager.class, Catalog.class})
public class CatalogTest {

@MockBean
private Db db;

@Autowired
private CaffeineCacheManager cache;

@Autowired
private Catalog catalog;

@Test
void cacheTest(){
   when(db.someDbMethod()).thenReturn(....);

   catalog.getItems();
   catalog.getItems();

   verify(db, times(1)).someDbMethod();

   assertTrue(cache.get(SOME_KEY).isPresent());//if you want to check that cache contains your entity
}

}
```

You will have really cache bean and a chance to check times of call your mock Db and also you can get cache key in your test.

Comment: Just tried that and in addition to the verification error I get a `java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods`

I've been told that I shouldn't really be testing spring cache itself which I agree. Thanks for the answer, it was worth giving it a try.

Comment: So, in my case, I really wanted to know that my cache and cache evict work correctly:)I'm pretty sure that's necessary, but you can think other, sure)